Узнать длину определенной строчки(текст) в HTML блоке
.post {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    font-size: 15px;
}

В блоке текст, присутствуют html теги, вроде span/p. Без наружных и внутренних отступов.

Как узнать, что в блоке, текст занимает более 3 строчек?
Как подсчитать длину третей строчки в px, с целью добавить кнопку на
развертывание, именно на окончание строчки?


Вы можете проверить есть ли скролл в блоке, если есть - то сработало ограничение.

Какое ограничение, если скрол в блоке это не значит что окончание 3 строчки в конце. Окончание может быть и по центру блока.
